# Trigger para evitar duplicidad de datos en ORACLE

Tags: oracle, plsql

ando aprendiendo Oracle y me surgió un problema. 
Tengo mi tabla Charla:

```
create table Charla (
   id_charla number,
   codigo_usuario number,
   fecha_charla date,
   fecha_fincharla date
)
```

Ahora, cree un disparador para que no me permita ingresar una "Charla" si ya se registró una anterior con el mismo codigo_usuario. Este es mi trigger:

```
create or replace trigger DISCHARLA
before insert on CHARLA
for each row
begin
if :new.codigo_usuario = :old.codigo_usuario then
            Raise_Application_Error(-20099,'NO PUEDE REGISTRAR OTRA CHARLA SI AUN MANTIENE CHARLA VIGENTE.');
end if;
end DISCHARLA;
```

Pero aún así me sigue permitiendo ingresar Charlas con el mismo código de usuario. Alguna ayuda o recomendación para mejorar mi trigger que no funciona.

Gracias.

Comment: ¿estás seguro que el trigger sí se está disparando? (yo lo haría escribir alguna salida para confirmar). ¿Estás seguro que el trigger compiló sin errores?

Comment: me compiló sin errores por eso pienso que algo está mal en la estructura

Comment: Revisa cómo se creó la tabla. Usar mayúsculas y minúsculas combinadas suele ser mala idea. Confirma que la tabla se creó con el nombre como lo indicas en el trigger. De nuevo, busca confirmar que el trigger se está disparando, hazle debug.

Comment: ya probé poniendo todo en mayúsculas o minúsculas y nada, cuando doy en el debug de mi disparador me sale esto: Conectando a la base de datos PNPPP.
Ejecutando PL/SQL: ALTER SESSION SET PLSQL_DEBUG=TRUE
Ejecutando PL/SQL: CALL DBMS_DEBUG_JDWP.CONNECT_TCP( '127.0.0.1', '50471' )
El depurador ha aceptado la conexión de la base de datos en el puerto 50471.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En un trigger Insert, las variables :old son nulos, solo las variables :new tienen valor del nuevo registro según cada columna o campo de la tabla.
En la línea:

```
if :new.codigo_usuario = :old.codigo_usuario then
```

Siempre evaluara falso (aún que las dos valores tengan NULL, **Null <> Null**)

Lo que requieres es crear un indice único que tenga el campo o columna **codigo_usuario**, algo como lo siguiente:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IDX_CHARLA_CODIGO_USUARIO
ON CHARLA (CODIGO_USUARIO);
```

Y en tu aplicación o programa cliente, atrapar el error **DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX excepción: ORA-00001.** para mostrar el el mensaje adecuado al usuario. O usar un procedimiento almacenado para hacer la inserción y dentro de él atrapar el error arriba mencionado y usar **RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR** con el mensaje para el usuario final.

Saludos

Comment: Si, en eso estaba pensando, pero que pasaría si quisiera ingresar una charla con el mismo id_usuario pero con fechas distintas. Ejemplo: en el primer registro id_usuario sea 1 y tenga su fecha de charla el 01-01 y como fin de charla el 03-01. Ahora si quisiera ingresar otro registro del mismo usuario pero con fecha de charla el 02-01 y como fin de charla el 04-01 no me debería permitir, en este caso si puedo usar un trigger cierto?

Comment: Puedes poner mas columnas o campos de la tabla en el indice único, o crear una llave primaria para las campos que hagan tu registro único, es parte de la definición de tu base de datos. El problema define la solución que se requiere.

Comment: Entiendo, gracias por la aclaración :)